# Do you only need to call setDefault() once for TimeZone and Locale?

Tags: java, android, calendar

One of `Calendar.getInstance()` constructors accepts both `TimeZone` and `Locale`, and both `TimeZone` and `Locale` have a `setDefault()` function that is a synchronized method.

In the context of Android, does this mean I only need to call this once on Activity `onCreate()`? If I do so, what if the Activity is paused and resumed? Alternatively, can I call these `setDefault()` on my custom Application class `onCreate()` on forget about how Android lifecycle could affect the value of my Calendar?

Most importantly, what could be the best practice of `setDefault()` usage in Android?

Comment: Best practice is not to call them. They default to phones settings, which means users preference, so why would you want to change them to something else?

Comment: @Andreas your statement is inaccurate according to doc in TimeZone.class: `Overrides the default time zone for the current process only. param timeZone a custom time zone, or {code null} to set the default to the user's preferred value.`

Comment: How does that say I'm wrong? I said that the default of `TimeZone` and `Locale` are already set from phone's settings, aka users preferences. Your quote does not contradict that. It only defines what happen if you call them, and I was talking about not calling them at all.

Comment: @Andreas OK I suppose I rushed to the conclusion that your statement represents the purpose of `setDefault()` before even understanding it carefully. On that, I say sorry, these things happen when you're close to deadline. Back to why would I use `setDefault()` in the first place is because the app I'm writing will only be available in 1 specific country and I just need to be 100% certain that all devices have the same `TimeZone` and `Locale`. Yes it is not a good practice for every other apps but I believe my goal for this particular app is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have to reiterate @Andreas' point that you really should not do this; if you must, then it should be sufficient to call them once for the entire process, as they are stored in `static` fields.

If you have a subclass of Application, it should be sufficient to override `Application.onCreate()` and set the values there.

If you're worried about only having a single set of localized strings, the better suggestion would be to put all of your translated strings into the default `values` directory (usually for `en` strings, but if it's your only translation, this is the best approach). This way, it doesn't matter what locale the user is in, they will only see this set of strings.